# Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, asymptote

I have recently started using LaTeX and have found it amazing. I now use LaTeX for all my documents :). However, now that I need to include some graphs and diagrams in my documents, I have found the `Asymptote` package, and seen that it is very powerful. I am having some issues using it though.

Firstly I would like to know the syntax for embedding asymptote code into LaTeX, and secondly if there is any convenient way to compile the whole document, in one command, I used to do my diagrams in mathematica, where I would import the picture and compile the whole document with a single `pdflatex` command.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For embedding Asymptote code in a LaTeX file, you can use the [`asymptote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote) LaTeX package:

```
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
```

For document global Asymptote definitions use the `asydef` environment:

```
\begin{asydef}
...
\end{asydef}
```

For your Asymptote code use the `asy` environment, possibly within a figure environment with caption:

```
\begin{asy}
...
\end{asy}
```

Run (pdf)LaTeX, then Asymptote, then (pdf)LaTeX again, such as:

```
pdflatex filename
asy filename-1.asy
pdflatex filename
```

For a convenient way, you can use [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/).

For more information, have a look at [7 LaTeX usage](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html#LaTeX-usage) in the Asymptote documentation. There's a complete LaTeX example with several Asymptote graphs and a How-to for compiling and using `latexmk`.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to configure `latexmk` for smooth compilation? It seems the links to `latexmkrc` are broken.

Comment: @juliohm Perhaps post it as a new question - I don't use `latexmk` myself.

Comment: My mistake, the file `latexmkrc` is still there in the repository under the `doc/` directory. All the user has to do is copy it to the project directory.

Answer (score 5):

You will find a guide to using Asymptote in LaTeX documents at [Art of Problem Solving Wiki](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Asymptote_%28Vector_Graphics_Language%29). They also have an [Asymptote forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=519) which allows you to render Asymptote code in the posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't must use asymptote you can find many other solution to use graphics in LaTeX. Please check [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) and [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). I think you'll find many useful examples and packages.