# asymptote giving me an error: could not load module 'example_01'

Tags: asymptote, makefile, arara

On page 3 of Dario Teixeira's **Asymptote and LaTeX**, the following simple example is provided:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}
size (3cm);
draw (unitcircle);
\end{asy}
\caption{Embedded Asymptote figures are easy!}
\label{fig:embedded}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I saved this in a file called `example_01.tex` and then following the instructions tried to compile by running from the command line:

```
latex example_01
asy example_01
latex example_01
```

But `asy` complains:

```
error: could not load module `example_01`
```

I'm using TeXLive 2013 on Mac OS X.  Any suggestions about what I need to do or am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that there was a `example_01-1.asy` file in my directory.  I ran `asy` on this and then recompiled my LaTeX file and everything seems to work out fine.

How do I get `asy` to find the correct files to compile on?  In particular, if I have multiple `asy` environments, is there a straight forward way to get `asy` to compile each file without me having to do through by hand telling it which files it needs?

### Solutions I've tried

**Using: make**

I can create a *makefile* as follows:

```
example_01.dvi : example_01.tex
           latex example_01.tex
           asy example_01-*
           latex example_01.tex
```

Or

```
example_01.pdf : example_01.tex
           pdflatex example_01.tex
           asy example_01-*
           pdflatex example_01.tex
```

Both of which work.

**Using: arara**

My usual approach is to use `arara`.  Since `arara` doesn't know `asy` I have to define my own `asy.yaml` file which I tried to do as follows:

```
!config
identifier: asy
name: asy
commands:
 - <arara> asy  @{getBasename(file)}-*
arguments: []
```

but the problem with this is that `arara` doesn't recognize *wildcard* specifiers for the file name.  Any suggestions about how to get `arara` to recognize *wildcards* or to get `arara` to feed the necessary files to `asy` for it to compile?

Comment: Which automation tool you use ? [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast Recently, I've been using `arara`.  But `arara` doesn't seem to allow *wildcards* in the file name.  I suppose I could just go with `make` and a `makefile` since wildcards are tolerated there.

Comment: Refer `latexmk` section of [Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36392/15717): open `gedit $HOME/.latexmkrc` and add `sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");` as in [ctan asymptote latexmkrc script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/asymptote_latexmkrc). No idea on `arara` with `asy` and `make` as well

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to answer: But feel free to add/edit

Refer latexmk section of [Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36392/15717):

open `gedit $HOME/.latexmkrc` 
and

```
add sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");} 
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy"); 
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy"); 
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

as in [ctan asymptote latexmkrc script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/asymptote_latexmkrc). I have no idea on arara with `asy` and `make` as well