# Asymptote not showing

Tags: texshop, asymptote

I have the package `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}` and I am trying to display the following Asymptote figure:

```
\begin{asy}
size(200);
pair A,B,C,D;
A=(0,0);
B=(200,0);
C=(200,150);
D=(0,150);
draw(A--B--C--D--cycle);
label("A",A,(-1,0));
label("D",B,(0,-1));
label("C",C,(1,0));
label("B",D,(0,1));
label("E",(200,85),(1,0));
dot((200,85));
draw((0,0)--(200,85));
draw((0,150)--(200,85));
label("$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 30^\circ$",anglemark((200,85),D,C),SE);
label("$80^\circ \ \ \ $",anglemark(A,(200,85),D),W);
\end{asy}
```

I'm just getting a blank. No error messages but it's showing nothing. I'm using TeXShop on a Mac, if that helps any. Any help would be highly appreciated!

*Update*: **Torbjørn T.** was nice enough to help me figure out why nothing was showing. Now, I am getting a figure without the desired anglemarks, which is a bit annoying. My code is as is in the OP. Does anybody know what's going on with the angle marks?

---

**For Torbjørn T.**

Here is a screenshot of what I am getting:

[image: Screenie]

I have already following the steps that you told me about earlier.

Comment: Did you run `asy` on the generated file?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "run `asy`"? My brain is not doing well today, sorry about that!

Comment: When you compile a document containing an asymptote figure such as that, it generates a separate file containing Asymptote code called e.g. `filename-1.asy`. You have to compile this with the Asymptote program, by issuing `asy filename-1.asy` in a terminal, which generates the figure, and then run `pdflatex` again, to place it in the document.

Comment: Ah, okay, I do see a `.asy` file in the same folder as the `.tex` file. Now, when I open it, it just shows the Asy code with a few extra stuffages. From here, what do you mean by "issuing `asy filename-1.asy` in the terminal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the command line?

Comment: The command line of TeX? Yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10214/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-ahaan-rungta)

Comment: Which chat room?

Comment: See also [Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36392)

Comment: @henrique That's exactly where I found it. I couldn't find the answer to my question there. Is it there or am I blind?

Comment: Follow the link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10214/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-ahaan-rungta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Asymptote part

The first thing you need for that Asymptote code is a module called `olympian`, that can be downloaded here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=519&t=165767 This adds support for `anglemark` and more.

It is the file attached to the first post in that thread. Save it as `olympian.asy` in the same folder as your `.tex` file. To use the module, add `import olympian;` to the Asymptote code.

Next, you want to draw the arcs, so instead of having the `anglemark` within the labels, it seemed necessary to have it in a `draw` command, so

```
draw(anglemark(E,D,C));
draw(anglemark(D,E,A));
label("$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 30^\circ$",D,SE);;
label("$80^\circ \ \ \ $",E,W);
```

`E` is the point `(200,85)`.

The default size of the arc is quite small, it can be increased by adding

```
markscalefactor=3;
```

Adjust the value to your needs.

I don't know what is the best to label angles, but I've added a suggestion:

```
label("\small$30^\circ$",shift(35*dir(-7))*D);
```

This label is placed at `D`, but `shift`ed `35` units in the `dir`ection `-7` degrees. The `\small` command makes the font a little smaller. Perhaps not necessary, but it was a bit cramped in the top left corner.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
import olympiad;
size(200);
pair A,B,C,D,E;
A=(0,0);
B=(200,0);
C=(200,150);
D=(0,150);
E=(200,85);
draw(A--B--C--D--cycle);
label("A",A,(-1,0));
label("D",B,(0,-1));
label("C",C,(1,0));
label("B",D,(0,1));
label("E",E,(1,0));
dot(E);
draw(A--E--D);
markscalefactor=3;
draw(anglemark(E,D,C));
draw(anglemark(D,E,A));
label("\small$30^\circ$",shift(35*dir(-7))*D);
label("\small$80^\circ$",shift(35*dir(180))*E);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

### Compilation

When compiling the above with `pdflatex`, a file called `<filename>-1.asy` is generated. To generate the image, this has to be compiled with the Asymptote program, so run

```
asy <filename>-1.asy
```

from a command line/terminal. Compile your `.tex` file again with `pdflatex` and the image should be included in your document.

You could also open the `.asy` in TeXshop file and compile it with the Asymptote engine, mentioned by Alan Munn in a comment.

Finally, it should be possible to do this compilation automatically with `latexmk`, but I wasn't successful in my attempts (I probably did something wrong).

### Output of above code

[image]

Comment: In TeXShop there is an Engine for `asymptote` so you don't need to do anything from the command line. You can simply put `% !TEX TS-program = Asymptote` in your `.asy` file and typeset the file. The `Asymptote` engine needs to be in the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` folder (move it there from the Inactive folder if it's not active.)  You will need to restart TeXShop for the change to show up in the Typeset menu.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help, Torbjørn! I have put a well-deserved green check next to your response. But due to my ignorance, this is still not working. I downloaded the `olympiad` file on the AoPS site in the correct folder, then copied your code, and I get this error: `Undefined Control Sequence.`

Comment: @AhaanRungta That is a TeX-error. What more does it say, i.e. what is the undefined control sequence?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Since I cannot post screenshots as comments, I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @AhaanRungta I got that error one time last night, but I cannot remember what I did to fix it. Try deleting all the generated files (e.g. `<filename>-1.asy`, `<filename>-1.tex`, and any other files) and recompile.

Comment: Back to Square One. I deleted the stuff you told me to, tried re-compiling. It went back to its original status -- compiled but not showing the image. So I tried redoing the steps you told me yesterday, the Terminal procedure. I got the error message: `error: could not load module 'IDEAMATHUS2-1.asy'`. Yesterday, you told me to ignore it and just re-compiler. So I did that and I still get the blank thing. Sorry to pester you but this just doesn't seem to work how you made it work!