# Asymptote is not working in Latex

Tags: pdftex, asymptote

I am new in asymptote. I tried a code from AoPS. But it is not giving desired output. I am not getting any figure in the output. The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
Hello.  
I like to make pics with Asymptote like this one:
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{asy}
    import graph;
    size(1inch);
    filldraw(circle((0,0),1),yellow,black);
    fill(circle((-.3,.4),.1),black);
    fill(circle((.3,.4),.1),black);
    draw(arc((0,0),.5,-140,-40));
  \end{asy}
\end{figure}
\par It makes me happy, 
since I can still type my normal LaTeX stuff around it: 
\(\int_0^{\pi}{\sin{x}}\,dx=2\)
\end{document}
```

The output which I am getting is

[image]

Comment: Lets assume the file name of your example is test.tex.
Try the following three commands:
`pdflatex test.tex`
`asy test-1.asy`
`pdflatex test.tex`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto  I am not understanding exactly what you are saying. Please elaborate.

Comment: in your source file you can add "\immediate\write18{asy \jobname*.asy}" after the last asy environment, and compile with the -shell-escape option, since you have to process yourself the asy command

Comment: @gigiair I did it but I am getting the same output.

Comment: probably you need a second compilation to insert the produced image in your document (-shell-escape not needed for this second compilation)

Comment: What is your compiler? texstudio or texmaker

Comment: @justonly neither texstudio nor texmaker are compilers, find out more

Comment: There is not enough information in this question, so it's impossible to help the OP; nevertheless it's likely that the OP is not running `asy` in the middle. For general reader coming across this question, refer to [pdftex - Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/using-asymptote-with-pdflatex?rq=1) for instruction to use Asymptote.